# How to change label text by the value of Progress View

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm trying to make an app that, when the progress bar comes 10%, 20%, 30% etc... shows an different text on a label. Can you help me on the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading or downloading something asynchronously, you can do this whenever you think your label text should change:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        label.text = newText
                    })
```